# unable to withdraw from the contract

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I have a very simple contract, and it works on remix. I'm able to deposit (fallback) and withdraw.
I want to do it on my webapp with web3js library.

the contract has these functions

```
fallback() external payable {}

 modifier onlyOwner(address caller) {
        require(caller == _owner, "You are not the owner of the contract");
        _;
    }

function getContractAmount(address caller) public view onlyOwner(caller) returns (uint256){
    return address(this).balance;
}

function withdraw() external {
  address payable to = payable(msg.sender);
  to.transfer(getContractAmount(to));
}
```

on my webapp I'm able to interact with the other function of my contract, so I imported address contract and ABI as well.

I have this function

```
contract.methods.withdraw().call().then((res) => {
    console.dir(res)
    $('#info').html(res);
  })
    .catch(revertReason => {
      console.log({ revertReason });
      $('#info').text(revertReason);
    }
 )
```

But I'm not able to retrieve the amount of my smart contract (yes the smart contract has ether)

with console.dir, I get "u"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [call()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.1/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) method is for read-only calls.

Since the `withdraw()` function changes the state, you need to [send()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.1/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send) a transaction.

```
contract.methods.withdraw().send({
    from: senderAddress
})
```

Your web3 instance or the node needs to know the private key to the `senderAddress` Use [wallet.add()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.1/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add) to add the private key to the web3 instance.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using metamask as well, I connect my account and I'm able to do the withdraw without any extra operation (like sign the transaction). Same for the send if I use web3 with `sendTransaction`

Comment: I can read `It will then sign locally using the private key of that account, and send the transaction via web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction().` https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction

Comment: @foo_bar Are you using a local emulator such as Ganache or Truffle node? Executing the function without signing would be expected in case, as the node emulator knows your private key, so you don't have to sign it on the app or via MetaMask.

Comment: I'm using just hardhat with waffle and ethers.js (https://hardhat.org/guides/waffle-testing.html#setting-up)

Comment: @foo_bar Hardhat is an emulator as well. So it knows your private key, and you don't have to sign the transaction any other way... Just mind that on public networks, the node will not know your private key, so on a public network you'll have to sign the transaction either by passing the private key to the app or through MetaMask.

Comment: Thanks, I will deploy it to testnet to understand it. thanks

Comment: I'm looking to emulate the real behaviour even with hard hat, but I don't find anything about it.